# Counting function in a "for" loop

Tags: python

I am doing some testing for my code in Python 3.6 and I need to count the number of SUCCESS and FAILURE. I do not know the results before because it depends of the user input.

```
for i in range (len(list_password)) :

        if final_password (list_password[i]) == list_result[i] :
              print(list_password[i]+"-----SUCCESS")
        else :
              print(list_password[i]+"-----FAILURE")
```

So at the end I should have. You have xx SUCCESS and xx FAILURES but the count function does not work here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a count into your `if/else` branches

```
success = 0
failure = 0

for i in range (len(list_password)) :
    if final_password (list_password[i]) == list_result[i] :
        success += 1
        print(list_password[i]+"-----SUCCESS")
    else :
        failure += 1
        print(list_password[i]+"-----FAILURE")
print('Successes: {} Failures: {}'.format(success, failure))
```

Comment: @Laura1999 Your welcome! Appreciate if you accepted answer, cheers :)